# Open a URL in Firefox in current tab/window from a Windows application?

Tags: firefox

I have a Windows application that works with Firefox.  If Firefox is already open, I'd like to have it open a given URL in the current tab+window as is currently showing.  Our application tends to open a lot of URLs and reusing the same browser window makes the most sense.  I already have a COM application that works with Internet Explorer, but haven't been able to find something similar for an external application to work with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this in Firefox is to set the `browser.link.open_newwindow` preference to 1. Unfortunately this also stops all in-page links from opening a new tab or window.

If you use [SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/) as your default browser then you can use the Preferences window under Tabbed Browsing or Link Behaviour to make links from external applications open in the current tab.